# intergal of $|f(x)|/f(x)$

Tags: absolute-value

Is there a way to take the integral of $\frac{\lvert f(x)\rvert}{f(x)}$ in terms of x?

I'm a little new to integrals, but I've had experience with derivatives, so I was thinking there was a chain rule for integrals, but I couldn't find an effective way.

Comment: Hint: this simplifies immensely as a piecewise function.

Comment: Hint: $|y|/y=1$  when $y>0$ and $|y|/y=-1$ when $y<0$.

Comment: I know that, but I don't know the reverse chain rule

Comment: The reverse of the chain rule is [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: Integration by substitution is a very poor choice of techniques for solving this integral, just as the chain rule is a very poor choice for taking the derivative of $\frac{\lvert f(x)\rvert}{f(x)}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ g(x) = \frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)} $

Then g(x) can be defined by breaking it into three intervals as follows:

g(x) = 
1, if f(x) > 0

Not defined, if f(x) = 0

-1, if f(x) < 0

Integrating the function interval-wise:

x, if f(x) > 0

Not defined, if f(x) = 0

-x, if f(x) < 0

The integral can be written as one single term too, i.e. $ x \cdot \frac{|f(x)|}{f(x)} + C $